# Unable to set slug to value used previously

Tags: entries

I have an entry whose slug I would like to set to 'archive', but when I save it, it is 'archive-1'. There is no existing entry with slug of 'archive' (`craft.entries.slug('archive')` returns null). There have been previous entries with that slug.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the caches?

Comment: Have tried clearing the caches. Doesn't help, but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that the uri needs to be unique. I found the duplicate uri by finding my entry in craft_elements_i18n, and looking for other entries with the uri I wanted.

Comment: Yes Marion, that's exactly what I wanted you to do. Sorry for my poor description.

Comment: slug was unique, but I had a single using that uri. But you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Entry slug, entry uri, to me it's all the same ;)

Answer (score 2):

There probably is still an (maybe corrupted) entry in the db with that slug. Have a look at the entries-content table, sort it by slug and you possibly see an entry responsible for your problem.

Comment: craft_elements_i18n table? No slug archive there. If I try to change the slug in the db (in that table) to 'archive', I get this error from mysql: Duplicate entry 'news/archive-en_us' for key 'craft_elements_i18n_uri_locale_unq_idx' so somewhere in the db it remembers that slug

Comment: figured it out. The uri needs to be unique.